# Minipage environment

Tags: minipage, width

I am using `minipage` environment in one slide of my `beamer` presentation. Basically, what I would like to have is the following:

top of the slide: a picture on the left and some description on the right. The text on the right should be in smaller fonts that usual.

Bottom of the slide: add additional information (using regular font size).

I wrote the following:

```
\newcommand\Fat{\fontsize{7}{7.2}\selectfont}
\section{Extras}
\subsection{Personal Profiles} 
\begin{frame}{The minipage environment}
\frametitle{Extras}
\framesubtitle{Personal Profiles}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=3cm]{images/PN}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\Fat
Adam Smith (B.Sc. London, M.Sc. and Ph.D. New York, M.Sc. by Research Los Angeles) Full
Professor of Physics (Hong Kong) and Visiting Professor of Physics (Milan). He was a Fulbright Research Fellow at Carnegie
Mellon University.
\end{minipage}\bigskip\\
Adam Smith is currently working on three project
\end{frame}
```

Everything works fine. The only point is that I would like to have the text on the right hand side in the `minipage` environment better distributed (i.e. I would like to have it in less and longer rows). How I can do that?

Comment: Hi All, sorted out. I changed \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} in \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\section{Extras}
\subsection{Personal Profiles} 

\begin{frame}{The minipage environment}{Extras}{Personal Profiles}

\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{l}{2.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
{\RaggedRight\small% Your font (size) choice
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis 
a metus nec pulvinar. 
Quisque sed rhoncus dui. Proin eget nisi mi. Quisque tempor mauris 
vestibulum, efficitur 
risus quis, auctor est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent consectetur 
mattis libero ac 
pellentesque. Suspendisse varius est eros, sed porttitor velit 
tincidunt vel. Vestibulum 
sodales quam sem, sit amet fermentum tellus luctus a.\par}

\bigskip        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis 
a metus nec pulvinar. 
Quisque sed rhoncus dui. Proin eget nisi mi. Quisque tempor mauris 
vestibulum, efficitur 
risus quis, auctor est. Aliquam erat volutpat.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, where you set the image and accompanying text in a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). The "image column" is set using `l` and therefore stretches with the image width - you specify the width already. The "text column" is set using `X` which uses the remaining part of the `\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{Extras}
\subsection{Personal Profiles} 
\begin{frame}{The minipage environment}
  \frametitle{Extras}
  \framesubtitle{Personal Profiles}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.7\normalbaselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=3cm]{example-image}} &
    \raggedright\small% Your font (size) choice
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis a metus nec pulvinar. 
    Quisque sed rhoncus dui. Proin eget nisi mi. Quisque tempor mauris vestibulum, efficitur 
    risus quis, auctor est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent consectetur mattis libero ac 
    pellentesque. Suspendisse varius est eros, sed porttitor velit tincidunt vel. Vestibulum 
    sodales quam sem, sit amet fermentum tellus luctus a.
  \end{tabularx}

  \bigskip

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis a metus nec pulvinar. 
  Quisque sed rhoncus dui. Proin eget nisi mi. Quisque tempor mauris vestibulum, efficitur 
  risus quis, auctor est. Aliquam erat volutpat.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The default alignment of the image is at its baseline. Lowering it (using a negative `\raisebox{<len>}`) aligns it at the top of the "text column".

You can fiddle around with you font or alignment selection above.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good idea, as well as th one below. I will keep those suggestions to amend my text. Thanks a lot again.